# Why is the file image size of the texture different from the size when loaded in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I used 5.01KB of texture 'Texture2D.LoadTexture()' I expected about 8KB.
but this memory alloc is 2.8MB

why texture alloc memory is more size?

Sample Code

```
private Texture2D[] m_SaveTextures = null;

public void Start()
{
    string path = "../Directory/";
    m_SaveTextures = new Texture2D[]
    {
        GetTexture(path + "Red.png"),
        GetTexture(path + "Green.png"),
        GetTexture(path + "Blue.png"),
        GetTexture(path + "Black.png")
    };
}

private Texture2D GetTexture(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path)) return null;

    var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false)
    {
        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
    };
    texture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

    return texture;
}
```

Example image..

[image: This image size is about 64.0KB]

Unity Profiler check image

[image: Unity Profiler check image]

Answer (score 1):

Because png is a compressed image file, but the texture you are loading it into is not.  `TextureFormat.ARGB32` is not a compressed format, so the memory cost is 32 bits per pixel.

You can lower the memory footprint by using one of the compressed formats, like DXT5, if your target platform supports it.